# Google Search to show only results with IP addresses

Tags: google-search

Is there a way that I could get Google Search to return only results with IP addresses in the URL?

Comment: Maybe for a specific one, but why would you want to do that in a general case?

Comment: I am doing a Google hacking lesson at uni. I was asked to search for unsecured cctv cameras. I did a search for `inurl:indexFrame.shtml"Axis Video Server"` however, there were other results that were not really cameras. I was wondering if i could optimize the search so that it returns results with IP addresses in the URL only

Answer (score 3):

A difference I can see to differentiate between IP address URLs and non-IP address URLs, is the TLD at the end of 'normal' URLs.

Thus, while searching, maybe you can just keep on filtering out TLDs you find getting in your way. E.g., if searching `inurl:indexFrame.shtml "Axis Video Server"`, and a .org url comes up in the results, add `-inurl:org` to the end of the string to simply get rid of all .org urls. Then `-inurl:com`, `-inurl:edu`, `-inurl:net`, `-inurl:jp`, etc.

Hopefully that won't inadvertently filter out pages you're still looking for and only isolate the IP address vs. domain name search issue :).

Comment: Not perfect. But it does filter out most of the unwanted results. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could simply filter out the results from all top level domains, e.g.:

> ["Axis Video Server" inurl:indexFrame.shtml -site:.com -site:.org -site:.net -site:.edu -site:.gov -site:.mil -site:.info -site:.us -site:.uk -site:.au -site:.ca -site:.nz -site:.ie -site:.io -site:.be -site:.sg -site:.jp -site:.pl -site:.de -site:.tv -site:.eu -site:.se -site:.ua -site:.cf -site:.nl -site:.tk -site:.gq](http://google.com/search?q=%22Axis%20Video%20Server%22%20inurl:indexFrame.shtml%20-site:.com%20-site:.org%20-site:.net%20-site:.edu%20-site:.gov%20-site:.mil%20-site:.info%20-site:.us%20-site:.uk%20-site:.au%20-site:.ca%20-site:.nz%20-site:.ie%20-site:.io%20-site:.be%20-site:.sg%20-site:.jp%20-site:.pl%20-site:.de%20-site:.tv%20-site:.eu%20-site:.se%20-site:.ua%20-site:.cf%20-site:.nl%20-site:.tk%20-site:.gq)

Of course, Google limits search terms to 32 *words*, so with [over a thousand](http://stats.research.icann.org/dns/tld_report/) top level domains there's simply no way to filter them all out. Unless your search term is really *specific* [*[cf.](https://www.exploit-db.com/google-hacking-database/)*], this would not scale well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not a perfect way to see only sites with IP addresses. But close enough :)